# Split hourly time-series in pandas DataFrame into specific dates and all other dates

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, time-series

I have a time-series in a pandas DataFrame at hourly frequency:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

idx = pd.date_range(freq="h", start="2018-01-01", periods=365*24)
df = pd.DataFrame({'value': np.random.rand(365*24)}, index=idx)
```

I have a list of dates:

```
dates = ['2018-03-20', '2018-04-08', '2018-07-14']
```

I want to end up with two DataFrames: one containing just the data for these dates, and one containing all of the data from the original DataFrame excluding all the data for these dates. In this case, I would have a DataFrame containing three days worth of data (for the days listed in `dates`), and a DataFrame containing 362 days data (all the data excluding those three days).

What is the best way to do this in pandas?

I can take advantage of nice string-based datetime indexing in pandas to extract each date separately, for example:

```
df[dates[0]]
```

and I can use this to put together a DataFrame containing just the specified dates:

```
to_concat = [df[date] for date in dates]
just_dates = pd.concat(to_concat)
```

This isn't as 'nice' as it could be, but does the job.

However, I can't work out how to remove those dates from the DataFrame to get the other output that I want. Doing:

```
df[~dates[0]]
```

gives a `TypeError: bad operand type for unary ~: 'str'`, and I can't seem to get `df.drop` to work in this context.

What do you suggest as a nice, Pythonic and 'pandas-like' way to go about this?

Answer (score 3):

Create boolean mask by [`numpy.in1d`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.in1d.html) with converted dates to strings or [`Index.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.isin.html) for test membership:

```
m = np.in1d(df.index.date.astype(str), dates)
```

---

```
m = df.index.to_series().dt.date.astype(str).isin(dates)
```

Or [`DatetimeIndex.strftime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DatetimeIndex.strftime.html) for strings:

```
m = df.index.strftime('%Y-%m-%d').isin(dates)
```

---

Another idea is remove times by [`DatetimeIndex.normalize`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DatetimeIndex.normalize.html) - get `DatetimeIndex` in output:

```
m = df.index.normalize().isin(dates)
#alternative
#m = df.index.floor('d').isin(dates)
```

Last filter by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df1 = df[m]
```

And for second DataFrame invert mask by `~`:

```
df2 = df[~m]
```

---

```
print (df1)
                        value
2018-03-20 00:00:00  0.348010
2018-03-20 01:00:00  0.406394
2018-03-20 02:00:00  0.944569
2018-03-20 03:00:00  0.425583
2018-03-20 04:00:00  0.586190
                      ...
2018-07-14 19:00:00  0.710710
2018-07-14 20:00:00  0.403660
2018-07-14 21:00:00  0.949572
2018-07-14 22:00:00  0.629871
2018-07-14 23:00:00  0.363081

[72 rows x 1 columns]
```

Answer (score 2):

one way to solve this

```
df = df.reset_index()

with_date = df[df['index'].dt.date.astype(str).isin(dates)].set_index('index')
##use del with_date.index.name to remove the index name, if required

without_date = df[~df['index'].dt.date.astype(str).isin(dates)].set_index('index')

##with_date

                        value
index                        
2018-03-20 00:00:00  0.059623
2018-03-20 01:00:00  0.343513
...

##without_date
                        value
index                        
2018-01-01 00:00:00  0.087846
2018-01-01 01:00:00  0.481971
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to solve this:

Keep your dates in `datetime` format, for example through a `pd.Timestamp`:

```
dates_in_dt_format = [pd.Timestamp(date).date() for date in dates]
```

Then, keep only the rows where the index's date is not in that group, for example with:

```
df_without_dates = df.loc[[idx for idx in df.index if idx.date() not in dates_in_dt_format]]
df_with_dates = df.loc[[idx for idx in df.index if idx.date() in dates_in_dt_format]]
```

or using pandas apply instead of list comprehension:

```
df_with_dates = df[df.index.to_series().apply(lambda x: pd.Timestamp(x).date()).isin(dates_in_dt_format)]
df_without_dates = df[~df.index.to_series().apply(lambda x: pd.Timestamp(x).date()).isin(dates_in_dt_format)]
```